# How are these two lines of code different that one throws an error and the other doesn’t?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

```js
console.log("#1", "a12312a".match(/^\d+/)?.[0].length);
console.log("#2", ("a12312a".match(/^\d+/)?.[0]).length);
```

---

I was writing some code and stumbled upon something I don’t understand. In Chrome 89.0.4389.128 (Official Build) (64-bit), the code above gives this:

```
#1 undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The both lines look the same to me: `"a12312a".match(/^\d+/)?.[0]` is an `undefined`, and they are trying to read the property `length` of the `undefined`, which is supposed to throw a `TypeError`. But the first line did not, while the second did.

…Why? I’m confused. Am I missing something very basic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.match` returns null since the pattern doesn't match. So the comparison is between

```
null?.[0].length
```

and

```
(null?.[0]).length
```

This should make the process clearer. With `.` and `?.` chains, as they evaluate left-to-right, if at *any point* the expression on the left is `null` or `undefined`, the chain will stop there and evaluate the whole thing to `undefined`.

But if you break the chain by surrounding one of them in parentheses instead, you just get a plain expression inside the parentheses:

```
(undefined).length
```

without the special mechanics of the optional chain.

Optional chaining only functions along a *contiguous sequence* of property accesses and function calls. Any other operator in between (such as grouping parentheses) will break the chain.

Comment: So it affects the entire chain, not just its left and right operands, right? Does it mean that `customer?.details?.address?.city` and `customer?.details.address.city` are the same?

Comment: Only if only `customer` can be nullish. They're different in that if `details` is nullish and `customer` exists, an error will be thrown in the second version.

Comment: The “at any point” part in your answer confused me a little. I understood how the operator works though. Thank you.